# Removal of Dictionary from List

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file I read in as a list of dictionaries for each line.  I want to remove all entries in the list that have an EmailAddress of `''`.  I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv


def import_users(location_of_file):
    with open(location_of_file, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as openfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(openfile)
       for row in reader:
            yield row

def save_csv(data, location):
   with open(location, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
       fieldnames = ['EmailAddress', 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'Company', 'Department']
       writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
       writer.writeheader()
       for item in data:
           writer.writerow(item)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    users = list(import_users('C:\Temp\Example.csv'))
    for user in users:
        if user['EmailAddress'] == '':
            del user
        else:
            pass
    save_csv(users, 'C:\Temp\Output.csv')
```

But my results still have the entries with no email address.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `del user` will *not* remove the element from the list, and you shouldn't remove elements from lists while iterating over them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not change list items while irritating over them.

Instead

```
for user in users:
    if user['EmailAddress'] == '':
        del user
     else:
        pass
```

Do

```
users = filter(lambda user: user['EmailAddress'] != '', users)
```

Answer (score 5):

Iterating over a data structure that you are modifying is bad practice (and will lead to super annoying bugs). So you should make another list containing only the items you want. You can do this with a loop:

```
users = list(import_users('C:\Temp\Example.csv'))
filtered_users = []
for user in users:
    if user['EmailAddress'] == '':
        filtered_users.append(user)
save_csv(filtered_users, 'C:\Temp\Output.csv')
```

Or using pythons filter function:

```
users = list(import_users('C:\Temp\Example.csv'))
filtered_users = filter(lambda user: user.get('EmailAddress') != '', users)
save_csv(filtered_users, 'C:\Temp\Output.csv')
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to ever create the list in memory. You can pass around generators and iterators instead:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    users = import_users('C:/Temp/Example.csv')
    save_csv((user for user in users if user['EmailAddress'] != ''),
             'C:/Temp/Output.csv')
```

Comment: I have a few other things I need to do with the data after this initial cleanup.  Particularly, I need to run a check on the emails and, if certain elements exist, I need to add a value to the current dictionary.  How would I pull this out of the save_csv to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be better off making a new list rather than removing items:

```
users = [user for user in users if user['EmailAddress'] != '']
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the first `users` to `usersWithoutEmail` it doesn't cost anything to have a different variable name (since you are making a new list anyhow)

Comment: I would argue in this case there's no reason to keep the original users list, as it doesn't seem to be used otherwise. An even better answer might be: `users = [user for user in import_users('C:\Temp\Example.csv') if user['EmailAddress] != '']`, and never generate that interim users list variable

Comment: I agree with your argument. However, it does make it less easy to modify code in the future if for some reason you need both sets of information.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

Example data:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
#Read csv data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
#Get only the rows having email address
dfo = df[pd.notnull(df['EmailAddress'])]
#Save to a file
dfo.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with using pandas but this looks pretty easy as well.  Is there a way to iterate through and update fields easily with pandas as well?  Need to do some other modifications before I'm complete with the data.

Comment: @user987654321 yes you can do all that you are asking for. It has vast function, go through the 10 minute tutorial, you will be able to do lot more.